# Which html tag should i use to put code in blogpost

Tags: html

I want to put C, c++, JAVA and HTML code in my blogpost, I found many websites with blockquote, code and other tags. Which one should i use(Which one google will like). Please tell if any new HTML tag is available. Thanks

Comment: "code"... "code"... what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question “Which one google will like” is that Google search probably ignores whatever markup you would be using for code. At least there is statement from Google to the contrary or any empirical evidence of any impact.

From the early days of HTML, `code` markup has been defined to mean computer code (somewhat vaguely, but usually interpreted to cover programming languages and markup languages at least). There is no new markup for this. However, the W3C HTML5 draft remarks: “Although there is no formal way to indicate the language of computer code being marked up, authors who wish to mark code elements with the language used, e.g. so that syntax highlighting scripts can use the right rules, may do so by adding a class prefixed with "language-" to the element.” So you could write

```
<code class="language-C">i++</code>
```

But this is just a suggested convention, and probably not recognized as anything special by any relevant software; it’s just an idea about styling, really.

With few exceptions, the only real impact of using `code` markup is that it makes the font monospace by default (and reduces font size to about 90%).

The `pre` element indicates preformatted text, so it is basically presentational and can be replaced by the use of `white-space: pre` in CSS. In practice, it also implies monospace font by default (and reduces font size).

The `blockquote` element means, in theory, quotation from an external source. So it is quite orthogonal to being computer code or human language. In practice, it hardly has any other impact than setting up default margins on all sides.

None of the elements mentioned changes the rules for interpreting HTML markup in HTML documents. So you cannot directly write `a<b` or `<p>` or `a&b`; the characters `<` and `&` still need to be escaped by HTML rules.

In a broad sense, Google is not completely ignorant of the markup discussed here. Google *Translator* treats `code` content as essentially untranslatable (i.e., it keeps its content intact, instead of translating keywords and identifiers), which is mostly good (for code proper; not so much for comment). Oddly enough, it seems to treat `pre` and `blockquote` the same way, for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 4):

There is `pre` and `code`. That is what stackoverflow does.

```
<pre><code>
 Your code here
</code></pre>
```

As an added bonus, StackOverflow uses [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) to add syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It was very confusing as many out there are using different tags. Any new tag from W3C to do this job??

Comment: @RishikeshChincholkar which job?

Comment: There isn't a new tag for `<code>` because it already exists. Please read the description, it is exactly what you want: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element